# Signalr Blocks When Using With Many IFrames

Tags: iframe, signalr

I´m using Signalr 1.0.1. I use many iframes inside my page, each iframe represents an application. 
Each iframe has this code:

```
$(function () {
    $.connection.hub.url = $("#urlNotificationsServer").val();

    notificationsHub = $.connection.notificationsHub;

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        connected = true;
        notificationsHub.server.addGrupo($("#userCode").val());
    });
});
```

It doens´t matter the browser, when I create around 5 iframes, the Signalr can´t connect anymore, if I track the network, it freezes with "pending" status, and all my site freezes.
I´m sure that the problem is the Signalr because when I remove $.connection.hub.start()..., I don´t have any problem.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled signalr logging `$.connection.hub.logging = true;`? If so, can you paste the log you get?

Comment: What browser and version? Most browsers restrict the number of connections to one server to 6. If SignalR is using 6 "Forever frames" for streaming, you'll hit this limit.

Comment: You should try forcing the transport to be longpolling: `$.connection.hubs.start({ transport: 'longPolling' });`

Comment: EricLaw it seems that is related with 6 frames. I simulate 4 times and the site freezes after six connections. But the signalr is using serverSentEvents and not Forever Frames. Any idea how I can workaround it?

Comment: I already tried force longpolling, same problem.

Comment: EricLaw, please put your comment as answer, so I can mark it. Thanks, that´s the problem, I will find a solution for it.